# Prove that if Z is g-measurable and both E(Y) and E(YZ) exist but are not necessarily finite, then E(YZ|g) = ZE(Y|g).

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I know the proof of this for the case where E(Y) and E(YZ) are finite, but how can they prove when E(Y) and E(YZ) are not necessarily finite?
For finite state, first we prove for indicate functions and then for simple functions and finally for any arbitrary function. But what would it be like for a state that exists and is not necessarily finite?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For non-negative $Y$ and $X$ we can let $n \to \infty$ in $E(YZI_{\{Y \leq N , Z\leq N\}}|g)=ZI_{\{Y  Z\leq N\}} E(YI_{\{Y \leq N \}} |g)$ to see that the equation holds irrespective whether the conditional expectations are finite or not. [ Monotone Convergence Theorem holds for conditional expectations]. Now we can take differences to go to the general case as long as we don't run into $\infty -\infty$ and that is guaranteed by the assumption that the  conditional expectations exist.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your guide.